# c# BeginInvoke doesn't work

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke

I have this code

```
private delegate void InvokeDelegate();

private void OpenFormNewNote(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if(loop == 2)
    {
        string service = null;
        if (currentServiceName != null)
        {
            service = currentServiceName.Replace(" ", "");
        }
        NewNotePanel newNote = new NewNotePanel(e.FullPath, service, listOfService, Path, MyConn, ipAddress, imgFolder, Utente_id);
        newNote.TopMost = true;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        var result = newNote.ShowDialog();
        if(result == DialogResult.OK || result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            if(result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(Refresh));
            }
        }
        loop = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        loop++;
    }
}
```

And this is the Refresh() Function:

```
public void Refresh()
{

    noteContainer.Controls.Clear();
    page = 0;
    try
    {
        string Query = "SELECT a, v, b, cFROM note Where Servizio_ID = " + asd+ " AND Visibile = 1 order by ID desc limit 15 OFFSET " + (pageIndex * page) + " ;";
        MySqlCommand MyCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader;
        if (MyConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();// Here our query will be executed and data saved into the database.  

            while (MyReader.Read())
            {

                CreateNotePreview(MyReader.GetString("a"), MyReader.GetString("b"), MyReader.GetString("c"), MyReader.GetString("d"));
            }
            MyReader.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Since OpenFormNewNote is called when the "Change" event of FileSystemWatcher is triggered.. of course it runs on a separated thread. Instead Refresh() does some UI stuff and it can't be called directly from OpenFormNewNote() otherwise it gives a Cross-Thread exception. So I tried with delegate but when the codeflow arrives on the BeginInvoke part.. Nothing happens and the Refresh function is not called.

What should I do?

Comment: The code is buggy and you can easily shoot your left leg clean off.  Using ShowDialog() on a worker thread is a very bad idea with possible fatal consequences later.  Executing dbase queries on the UI thread is a bad idea.  Using Controls.Clear() is nasty, a rockhard requirement is to call Dispose() on controls you want to get rid of.  Consider getting ahead by setting the FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject to your main form, now you get the event raised on your UI thread.  Gives you a better shot at partitioning the code correctly.   Debug deadlock with Debug > Windows > Threads.

Comment: `BeginInvoke` works *just fine*; if you put a break-point in at the start of `Refresh`, does it get hit?

Comment: @MarcGravell it is not hit..

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please write and answer the SynchronizingObject filed solved my problem.. I can check your answer as correct.. thanks